# Find size of unknown type memory in kernel

Tags: c, memory, freebsd

I have an unknown `void* bufferpointer`. Is there away to find the memory size of the buffer. I do not have access to `malloc.h`, I do however have access to `sys/malloc.h` in Freebsd kernel.

Comment: Which kernel? How unknown? Do you know whether it is virtual memory? Etc.

Comment: I can not use those functions from malloc, because it is in kernel, but I do have access to sys/malloc.h, it is a limited version of malloc.h. It is Freebsd that I am using. And it is not virtual memory, it is just a user space buffer.

Comment: @lostdong12 Does FreeBSD often have "user space buffers" that are physical memory with physical addressing?

Comment: Kernels only know whether a user space pointer is aimed at a mapped page or not, and how many pages after that page are also mapped. If pages are 4096 bytes, and you pass down a 12 byte malloc chunk which is at the start of a page, but you tell the system call that it's 4096 bytes wide, the kernel will believe it; the entire 4096 page is a valid piece of virtual memory that it can read or write. The kernel can tell that the memory came from `mmap` or `sbrk`, and all the details which go with that. Just not details like "libc malloc broke this into 64 byte chunks, and this is one of them".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Linux kernel, if you have pointer to some virtual memory, it can be reversed back to the `struct page *` as well as the `struct vmap_area` or `struct vm_area_struct` which indicates what `mmap`-ed region it points to (from which you know the size).

The operating system needs these kinds of reverse mappings because without them it wouldn't be able to do things like, oh, handle a page fault, and then map the memory, and then extend an auto-growing mapping, if necessary and so on.

If you suspect the address is in space allocated by `vmalloc` (the kernel's own allocator for kernel-owned virtual memory) you can try `find_vmap_area` which searches through the red-black tree of `vmalloc` areas and returns a pointer to a `struct vmap_area`. That will be null if the address is not found there.

If you suspect the address is regular process virtual memory, then `find_vma` maybe able to find it. It returns a `struct vma_struct *` pointer, which is null if the lookup fails.

Both these structures give you information about the starting and ending address of the mapping which contains the address.

You're not going to get fine-grained information, like how big of a user-space `malloc` chunk is referenced by a pointer.

Also, I don't think you can reverse random addresses that point to memory which came from `kmalloc` to the allocation info.

Comment: Not sure why you accepted this, since your question is about FreeBSD.